# Pandas dataframe: merge three dataframes by two columns, ignoring most columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following three dataframes, which are "indexed" by two columns: there's a grouping `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, etc. and a numerical position within this group `148, 179, 188, 267, ...`.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"grouping": ["item1", "item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item2", ...],
        "positions": [148, 179, 188, 267, 693, 963, 979, ...],
        "metadata": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9, ...], 
        "unique_column1" : ['QLZX9J', 'L3FPRU', '69TVKF', 'N096NQ', 'JM89V5', 'W7JBOL', '63KKZZ', ...] }




data2 = {"grouping": ["item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item2", ...],
        "positions": [118, 241, 431, 448, 455, 677, 740, ...],
        "metadata": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9, ...], 
        "unique_column2" : [4714, 1178, 235, 47, 54, 89, 12, ...] }

data3 = {"grouping": ["item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", ...],
        "positions": [118, 148, 179, 188, 241, 431, 448,...],
        "metadata": [5, 1, 8, 3, 731, 189, 9, ...], 
        "unique_column3" : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', ...] }


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

df1
>>>    grouping positions  metadata unique_column1
0     item1       148         5         QLZX9J
1     item1       179         1         L3FPRU
2     item1       188         8         69TVKF
3     item2       267         3         N096NQ
4     item2       693       731         JM89V5
5     item2       963       189         W7JBOL
6     item2       979         9         63KKZZ
7     ....        ...       ...         ... 

df2
>>>    grouping positions  metadata unique_column2
0     item1       118         5           4714
1     item1       241         1           1178
2     item1       431         8            235
3     item1       448         3             47
4     item1       455       731             54
5     item1       677       189             89
6     item2       740         9             12

df3
>>>    grouping positions  metadata unique_column3
0     item1       118         5              a
1     item1       148         1              a
2     item1       179         8              a
3     item1       188         3              a
4     item1       241       731              a
5     item1       431       189              a
6     item1       448         9              a
```

I would like to merge these three dataframes by both `grouping` and `positions`, so that the row with `grouping` = `item1`, `positions` = `118` in `df2` is merged with the same row in `df3`. There are many columns between these dataframes which are the same, and shouldn't be copied over. In fact, the only unique column to be merged in the final merged dataframe in `df1` is `unique_column1` and in `df2` is `unique_column2`, etc.

How does one merge one column from three dataframes together, only using two columns as indices? This seems a bit more complicated than `pandas.merge()`

If an tem doesn't exist, it should be 0. The merged table should look like this:

```
merged 
grouping    positions    metadata    unique_column1    unique_column2    unique_column3
item1       118          5           0                 4714              'a'
item1       148          1           'QLZX9J'          0                 'a'
item1       179          8           'L3FPRU'          0                 'a'
item1       188          3           '69TVKF'          0                 'a'
item1       241          731         0                 1178              'a'
.........
```

Comment: Do all `unique_column*` columns start with the same text or, alternatively,  do you have/know a list of common columns?

Comment: @MaxU Yes, I know the list of unique columns. There is only one which should be merged in the end---the rest should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

jcols = ['grouping', 'positions']
ucols = ['unique_column1','unique_column2','unique_column3']

pd.concat([df.set_index(jcols)[df.columns.intersection(ucols)]
           for df in dfs],
          axis=1) \
  .reset_index() \
  .fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
   grouping  positions unique_column1  unique_column2 unique_column3
0     item1        118              0          4714.0              a
1     item1        148         QLZX9J             0.0              a
2     item1        179         L3FPRU             0.0              a
3     item1        188         69TVKF             0.0              a
4     item1        241              0          1178.0              a
5     item1        431              0           235.0              a
6     item1        448              0            47.0              a
7     item1        455              0            54.0              0
8     item1        677              0            89.0              0
9     item2        267         N096NQ             0.0              0
10    item2        693         JM89V5             0.0              0
11    item2        740              0            12.0              0
12    item2        963         W7JBOL             0.0              0
13    item2        979         63KKZZ             0.0              0
```

Comment: Does this drop all of the "repeated" columns in `df1` and `df2` that may exist post `pd.merge()`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, it will use `['grouping', 'positions']` columns for joining and all specified in `ucols` unique columns. All other columns will be ignored (dropped)

Comment: I understand now. Ah, I see how this works. Thank you.